# Multiple columns in group by clause in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, group-by

How to do Group by query (for e.g. Select column1,column2,min(value) from Foo_Bar where value> 100 **group by (Column1,Column2)** ) in hibernate? I wanted to have **multiple columns in group by** part.

Comment: group by can only be used when the other columns are the result of aggregate function (sum, count, avg, etc.), like in SQL: `select column1,column2,sum(value) from FooBar group by column1, column2`

Comment: yeah even I was trying to do the same just posted the wrong query before. As I have edited the question, can you please help for this modified query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select f.column1, f.column2, min(f.value)
from FooBar f
where f.value > 100
group by f.column1, f.column2
```

Comment: This is sql query and I wanted the hibernate equivalent of it.

Comment: It is perfectly fine JPQL query and works nicely with Hibernate. If names of attributes do not match to your entity, just change them. (+1).